# Get IP of Visitor, then name a .txt file after the visitor?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a system that will get the visitors IP, include some information, and then save that information in a .txt file with the file name of like... 10.0.0.1.txt.

I'm having some issues with it.

Here's some of the code:

```
$logfile = fopen($client_IP, 'a+');
fwrite($logfile, "\n".$_GET['c']);
fclose($logfile);
```

$client_IP is basically :

```
    $client_IP = $_Server['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Can anyone help me out?

The output file always either ends up empty, and causes an error stating that the file name cannot be empty, or it just outputs .txt.

I've tried multiple variations, but no success so far.

Comment: AFAIK, the `.txt` file should exist first before you can append to it.

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'.txt' ?

Comment: Just a suggestion but maybe the periods in the IP address are causing a problem. Try replacing them with underscores with str_replace.

Comment: @RonnyvandenBergh: even more nonsense. Do you really imagine the OP has some filesystem that doesn't allow a `.` in filenames? I think "I'm using a 30-year-old version of DOS" would have made it into the question.

Comment: @Wooble That's the reason I said AFAIK; which means I stand corrected.

Comment: Handbags at dawn! p.s. if your only writing (not reading) use "a" not "a+" (I checked the manual first LOL)

Answer (score 2):

It's

- `$client_IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` with `$_SERVER`
- make sure you have permissions on that folder

Answer (score 1):

I think $_Server['REMOTE_ADDR']; must be $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Not entirely sure but I think this can work.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the effect of sharing of IP addresses as they are dished out by ISPs... but you're right, use of $_Server gives notice (Win32)